# how can i write dynamic javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

how can i write dynamic javascript any simple example or any references.
thanking you

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>

<div id="flashPlayer">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">




   var so = new SWFObject("playerSingle.swf", "mymovie", "192", "67", "7", "#FFFFFF");
   so.addVariable("autoPlay", "yes");
   so.addVariable("soundPath","song.mp3");
   so.addVariable("overColor","#000044")
   so.addVariable("playerSkin","1") 
   so.write("flashPlayer");


</script>
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic javascript?

Comment: do you want to execute dynamic JS statements?

Comment: ya actually i place a audio player in my application.it is working fine when i place the audio file directly into that but in my application i have to play it dynamically that is the aduio file will come from querystring. when i ask for support for the technical team of the player they told me to write dynamic javascript if you want i place that code

Comment: Aren't you the guy mentioned on Meta, who took a commercial job and tried to abuse stackoverflow community to do the job for you?

Comment: no i did not ask any meta questions and i am not at all abuse stackoverflow and i respect the all stackoverflow members

Comment: i ask the question which are not know to me

Comment: I think this problem is a little more specific than "writing dynamic Javascript" and it's unanswerable without more details and code samples.

Comment: ya i will send the code to you Mr.deceze

Comment: just now i am edited my question Mr.deceze can u check please

Comment: Okay... So what's the part that's supposed to be dynamic and where does it come from?

Comment: it comes from the another page. when user click on particular audio (linkbutton which is in the home page) then the page redirect to the page where audio will going to play using query string i passing (arguments) the audio name to the page

Comment: when user click on any of the audio (home page) it redirect to playaudio.aspx page and start the palying the audio, i am sending the audio name by querystring

Comment: audio name should be (from querystring) which placed in the script.
like.. so.addVariable("soundPath","song.mp3");
 audio name "song.mp3" will change every time. audio name comes from query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use ASP.NET to parse the query string rather than javascript, something like this ought to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var so = new SWFObject("playerSingle.swf", "mymovie", "192", "67", "7", "#FFFFFF");
   so.addVariable("autoPlay", "yes");
   so.addVariable("soundPath", '<%= Request.QueryString["song"] %>');
   so.addVariable("overColor","#000044")
   so.addVariable("playerSkin","1") 
   so.write("flashPlayer");

</script>
```

However, if you do this, you will have a security hole - a custom-crafted URL could embed anything into the javascript executing on your page, including malicious code. You should use the [AntiXSS](http://antixss.codeplex.com/) library to javascript-encode the value from the query string before you insert it into your client-side javascript.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very broad question.

If you mean how can you use javascript to set the audio file parameter of the swf object, then if we take the code you already have and assume your URL to be something like http://mydomain.com/musicplayer.html?audio=mysong.mp3, there is a library at http://adamv.com/dev/javascript/querystring that can help. Using it should result in something similar to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   //assign variable to querystring
   var qs = new Querystring()

   //retrieve the parameter you want
   var requestedFile = qs.get("audio", "defaultsong.mp3")

   var so = new SWFObject("playerSingle.swf", "mymovie", "192", "67", "7", "#FFFFFF");
   so.addVariable("autoPlay", "yes");
   so.addVariable("soundPath",requestedFile);
   so.addVariable("overColor","#000044")
   so.addVariable("playerSkin","1") 
   so.write("flashPlayer");


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to interpret your question as dynamically generating Javascript and then executing it. If you are using Java 6, then you can do something like this

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine js = mgr.getEngineByExtension("js");
try {
   js.eval("print('Hello, world!')");
} catch (Exception e) { }
```

If you need to generate very complex JavaScript code, the I suggest you use a template library like [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)

Comment: thank you for response Mr.Chuk Lee just now i place the comment can u check the comment please

Comment: Ok your question above is not very clear either. I'm going to interpret it as you want to dynamically generate JS inside a web page and then return that web page to your user. 

One simple way, if you are doing it in Java, is to create a servlet mapping to /myapp/dymamicpage. Then what you do is use StringTemplate to generate the JS code, set the content type to 'text/html' and return it to your user.

Comment: Miss that part about querystring. So if you have something like this /myapp/dymamicpage?movefile=movie.avi then use HttpServletRequest.getParameter("moviefile") to retrieve the parameter(s)

Comment: i am using .net not java Mr.Chuk Lee

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have this URL:

http://www.myplayer.com&song=mysong.mp3

Being redirected to this page, you want to play the mysong.mp3.

In javascript you can read the url using the `window.location.href` property. You need to parse it yourself in order to extract the song.

This [link](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html) could help you with the parsing.